# setting datetime on jquery datetimepicker()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I've got a datepicker using jquery,

```
    $('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
    mask:'9999-19-39 29:59'
  });
```

However, on load, the display value is `____-__-__ __:__`
I want to change it so it displays `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

I tried the  below and it doesnt work, any idea what to do?

```
$('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
mask:'9999-19-39 29:59'});

$('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker('setDate', "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the below code should work:

```js
//Set DatePicker to October 3, 2008
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work, maybe because im using a datetimepicker rather than only datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
         defaultDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss',
     });
 });
```

Find the demo
**<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bqskjg30/10/)</kbd>**

Comment: thanks but it didn't work, the data format wasn't the detailed, it ended up like 7AugAug2015 etc..

Comment: @Luizarios I have added 6 external resources in Fiddle have you added all these?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the jsfiddle demo :)